# Insert random text in textbox cshtml javascript MVC3

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

Hi I am trying to make an MVC application where a random text can be entered in the text box. 
I have made this simple script to get a random word from an array

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function random() {
    var adjective = new Array('quick', 'pleasant', 'successive', 'interim',
    'optimistic', 'sensitive', 'temporary', 'reminiscent', 'drooly', 'muddy',
    'maddening', 'ceaseless', 'bawdy', 'earthy', 'european', 'aboard', 
    'innovative', 'broad', 'smelly', 'mad', 'reduced', 'plucky', 'glib', 'liable',
    'ratty', 'venomous', 'chivalrous', 'wide', 'moral', 'scary');
    rdm = Math.floor(Math.random() * adjective.length);
    document.getElementById("adj1").nodeValue = adjective[rdm];
}
```

and then I have something like

`

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.adj1)
    <button type="button" title="Random" id="1" onclick="random()">
        <img src="../../Content/themes/base/images/random.png" alt="" />
    </button>
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.adj1) 
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.adj1) 
</div>`
```

its seems that my code never reaches the random function, I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Are you sure the `random()` function isn't running?  Test this by adding a `alert('runs');` or something similar at the beginning of the function.

Comment: I tried that, no message :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
document.getElementById("adj1").value = adjective[rdm];
```

Comment: same output, nothing happens on click

Comment: your solution fixed, not sure why it didnt in the begining but now it works. Thank you